# How to fix an issue where importing a file fails when using a namespace

Tags: php

I am learning the php namespace and autoload function, I hope that autoloading will take effect when using the namespace, how can I make it work?

My php environment is php 7.3.1, The development tool I use is phpstorm

I tried to load the class automatically without using a namespace, which is fine, but if I use a namespace, I get an import error.

These three files are all in the same directory.

Directory Structure:

```
project
|    automatically-load-objects.php
│    autoLoadA.php   
│    autoLoadB.php
```

automatically-load-objects.php:

```php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once $class . '.php';
});

$obj1 = new \autoLoadTest\autoLoadA();
$obj2 = new \autoLoadTest\autoLoadB();
$obj1->classA();
$obj2->classB();
```

autoLoadA.php:

```php
<?php

namespace autoLoadTest;

class autoLoadA
{
    public static function classA()
    {
        echo 'Hello, this is classA!' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

autoLoadB.php:

```php
<?php

namespace autoLoadTest;

class autoLoadB
{
    public static function classB()
    {
        echo 'Hello, this is classB!' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I want the autoload to take effect, but in fact phpstorm gives some errors:

> Warning: require_once(autoLoadTest\autoLoadA.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Riven\Documents\Study\php\php-pracitice\Getting-started-with-php-programming\classes
>   and objects\first part\automatically-load-objects.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'autoLoadTest\autoLoadA.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\Users\Riven\Documents\Study\php\php-pracitice\Getting-started-with-php-programming\classes
>   and objects\first part\automatically-load-objects.php on line 4

Comment: You should [check out some tutorial](https://medium.com/@jodylecompte/making-sense-of-php-autoloading-ae1dd11678c2) about PSR-4-autoloading.

Comment: The error message is very clear: there is no file named `autoLoadTest\autoLoadA.php`. What is confusing about that?

Comment: hey peter, i don't know, These three files are all under the same directory, Isn't the namespace a virtual path? And, thanks, Magnus Eriksson, The URL you sent is a good tutorial.